# Twitter Android App - Source code

Tags: android, twitter

I wounder if the source code for Twitter android app is released??

Comment: Don't think it is. Why would it have to be?

Comment: cause they wrote that the source could would be opened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been anounced to be open sourced in the future, but it still isnt.

Comment: okej, thanks for the answer, have they announced a date for the release?

Answer (score 6):

See this tweet from a Google developer: http://twitter.com/#!/vdobjanschi/status/8775784206438400

> Twitter is now responsible to open source the app. Please direct your question to the Twitter Mobile team.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of - I've been searching as well and can find a number of "official" references to it being open sourced soon (namely: a post by Tim Bray in may - http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter 4 j ... is the answer. The SDk to integrate twitter to an Android app. [You could find the tutorial here](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html)

It provides various features as tweeting through code, make a tweet favorite, destroy favorite  for a tweet... And Of Course the authorizations