# How to decompile an APK or DEX file on Android platform?

Tags: android, disassembly, decompiling, malware-detection

Is it possible to decompile an APK package or DEX file on Android platform?
Are there any tools that can decompile an APK file?

Comment: do you mean by programmatically ?

Comment: This link has every answer that you need.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732882/reverse-engineering-from-an-apk-file-to-a-project

Comment: there are many in Play store someone can search it..

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You need Three Tools to *`decompile an APK`* file.

> 1. [Dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar) - Tools to work with android .dex and java .class files
> 2. [ApkTool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) - A tool for reverse engineering Android apk files
> 3. [JD-GUI](https://java-decompiler.github.io/) - Java Decompiler is a tools to decompile and analyze Java 5 “byte code” and the later versions.

for more [how-to-use-dextojar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257830/how-to-use-dextojar/19954951#19954951). Hope this will help You and all! :)

Comment: I think all these tools run in windows platform. can I import these jar files into my android project and then run in android platform

Comment: Rupesh Yadav@ In this process some code of line  is miss match to original code. www.decompileandroid.com/
from this web i able to decompile my code but both code are different why?

Comment: @Shailendrsingh the above is the standard process to decompile an APK and in case when obfuscation is enabled in app the decompiled classes code may differs.

Comment: ok
if obfuscation is enable in app.how can i get original code which are written in app?

Comment: @Shailendrsingh its possible only if you are having reverse mapping file, otherwise can`t get 100% out of an APK file.

Comment: [AppUse](https://appsec-labs.com/AppUse) collected all the above tools into one tool.

Answer (score 51):

Online APK Decompiler 
http://www.decompileandroid.com/
https://www.decompiler.com/
APK Decompiler App for Windows
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2493107

**Update 2015/12/04**
ClassyShark you can open APK/Zip/Class/Jar files and analyze their contents.
https://github.com/google/android-classyshark

**Update 2021/1/28**
https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ 
https://github.com/skylot/jadx

Comment: DecompileAndroid unfortunately doesn't decompile strings.xml correctly

Comment: ProGuard entirely remove R$string.class, but Android decompilers can reconstruct all information from resources.arsc. I think this DecompileAndroid hasn't implemented this kind of complicated function yet

Comment: thx for the update, 
jadx seems to work, although the export does not seem to work, so I cannot open the project in Android Studio

Answer (score 12):

I have created a tool that combines dex2jar, jd-core and apktool: https://github.com/dirkvranckaert/AndroidDecompiler
Just checkout the project locally and run the script as documented and you'll get all the resources and sources decompiled.

Answer (score 9):

An APK is just in `zip` format. You can unzip it like any other `.zip` file.

You can decompile `.dex` files using the `dexdump` tool, which is provided in the Android SDK.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7750547/116938 for more dex info.

Comment: *"An APK is just in zip format"*, true but many files including the `AndroidManifest.xml` don't unzip properly and are not readable...

Answer (score 6):

http://www.decompileandroid.com/

This website will decompile the code embedded in APK files and extract all the other assets in the file.

Comment: very nice web-site! I used it for a year. There is also alternative: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk/, which uses different approach (Jadx instead of Dex2jar + Jad)

Comment: @JqueryNinja check this for alternate  - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27981520/3879847

Comment: @RanjithKumar http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk/ after waiting for long hours in a queue, the website did decompile my apk. However, some java classes were missing. Isn't there any other alternative?

Comment: @JqueryNinja use showjava apk. This is better than others. but advertisment is more.. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava

Comment: @RanjithKumar showjava uses  javadecompilers.com/apk or jadx which does not decompile all java classes

Answer (score 5):

You can decompile an apk on Android device using this : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava

For more info look here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2601315

**EDIT: 28-02-2015**

For decompiling an apk you can use this tool: https://apkstudio.codeplex.com/license

If that doesnt help check this [link](http://s4mpl3d.me/?p=162)

Comment: The app never worked for me. It infinitely tries to perform "Decompiling to java" and them usually crashes..

Comment: then you should follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23924665/2736039 these solutions work very well

Comment: that solution has another problem - see my comment there ;)

Comment: I know that problem and to solve that I use Apk Tool. As much as I know you cant find a tool that does all the work. You have to use them all :)

Comment: check my edited answer I have found a new tool

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the apktool: http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/ which will also give you the xml res files. Along with that you can also use the dex2jar system which will output the dex file in the apk to a jar file that can be opened with JD-GUI and exported to standard java files.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use Android Multitool. You can make minor changes in the app like hiding GUI elements or modifying small part of Logic and rebuild the apk. Its easy to use and decompile/recompile apk and jar files. Here is the [Link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2326604) you can checkout.

Cheers