# Push notifications in Delphi XE6 are displayed

Tags: delphi, push-notification, delphi-xe6

I played with `TPushEvents` on Android for a while and noticed: when app is minimized push notification immediately goes right to the notification area. I suppose that this behaviour is defined in the native code (inside `com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMNotification`).

1. Can anyone confirm or refute my guess?
2. How this behaviour can be turned off? (I need to decide by myself whether notification should be displayed to a user.)

Comment: Where should the notification go instead in this case? (what is the desired behavior?)

Comment: @mjn (0) nowhere or (1) in the notification area or (2) in the notification area and stack with others. It should depend on a variable.

Comment: That is typical behavior for a notification. I tested it and it appears just like any other push notification.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to inherit FMXNativeActivity class and overrid its public void receiveGCM(Bundle bundle) method but not deal with pause condition.

Answer (score 0):

1. I myself can confirm this guess.
2. [Decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010367/how-to-decompile-a-apk-or-dex-file-on-android-platform) classes.dex, rewrite `com.embarcadero.gcm.notifications.GCMNotification` to suite your needs, compile and put it back inside classes.dex using the script from [here](http://www.blong.com/Articles/DelphiXE5AndroidActivityResult/ActivityResult.htm#JavaBuild).

   I'm just not sure it's legal.