# Retrieving an app build from android device

Tags: android, macos

I was working on a game using eclipse and cocos2d-x and through some freak accident I lost all of my data. However, the build of the app is still saved on my nexus tablet from when I would test my app. Is there any possible way for me to salvage the work I've done from what's left on my tablet?

Comment: and when I say all of my data, I mean all of my android SDK data, eclipse data, and the project itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to decompile the classes.Here is a tutorial :
http://pof.eslack.org/2011/02/18/from-apk-to-readable-java-source-code-in-3-easy-steps/

And another tutorial with an eclipse plugin:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-decompiler-plugin-for-eclipse/

And an older post here in s.o. :
[How to decompile an APK or DEX file on Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010367/how-to-decompile-a-apk-or-dex-file-on-android-platform)

Comment: Since I used cocos2d-x to make my app, it means all of my code is in C++, except these tutorials are making me convert the classes.dex to java class files.