# apptool decompile with AND APKTOOL

Tags: android

i want to decompile my recent apk to test is it.

i run the code

> `C:\Users\admin\apktool d OwnApp.apk`

but it's getting error with :

> Input file (OwnApp.apk) was not found or was not readable.

why am i getting this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Procedure for decoding .apk files, step-by-step method:

Step 1:

```
 1). Make a new folder and copy over the .apk file that you want to decode.
 2). Now rename the extension of this .apk file to .zip (e.g. rename from filename.apk to filename.zip) and save it.
 3). Now you can access the classes.dex files, etc. At this stage you are able to see drawables but not xml and java files, so continue.
```

Step 2:

```
 1). Now extract this .zip file in the same folder (or NEW FOLDER).
 2). Download dex2jar and extract it to the same folder (or NEW FOLDER).
 3). Move the classes.dex file into the dex2jar folder.
 4). Now open command prompt and change directory to that folder (or NEW FOLDER). 5). Then write d2j-dex2jar classes.dex (for mac terminal or ubuntu write ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex) and press enter.
 6). You now have the classes.dex.dex2jar file in the same folder.
 7). Download java decompiler, double click on jd-gui, click on open file, and open classes.dex.dex2jar file from that folder: now you get class files.
 8). Save all of these class files (In jd-gui, click File -> Save All Sources) by src name. At this stage you get the java source but the .xml files are still unreadable, so continue.
```

Step 3:

```
 1). Now open another new folder

 2). Put in the .apk file which you want to decode
 3). Download the latest version of apktool AND apktool install window (both can be downloaded from the same link) and place them in the same folder
 4). Open a command window apktool d myApp.apk (where myApp.apk denotes the filename that you want to decode)
 5). now you get a file folder in that folder and can easily read the apk's xml files.
```

this solutions is extracted from this StactOverflow site [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

you can download all the required libraries from here [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010367/how-to-decompile-an-apk-or-dex-file-on-android-platform)

Comment: coming years later to find the right answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Recompiling apk using apktool for MAC**:-

Process to **DeCompile** APK(Android Package):

- Open terminal and cd to apk directory
- type su
- apktool d <../../pathToMyAPK>

Process to **ReCompile** APK(Android Package):

- Open terminal and cd to apk directory
- type su
- apktool b <../../pathToMyAPKFolder>
- New apk is generated in  pathToMyAPK/dist/NewAPP.apk

->Now we need to sign the apk to be able to port to device.

To sign an apk:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore <path of my-keystore.keystore> <path of apk>  alias_name
```

Answer (score -1):

For Decompile,  Run Apktools Over CMD like `C:\\example: apktool d x.apk`

Comment: Just what?  Can you please re-edit your answer so it's more clear?

Comment: please complete answer

Comment: apktools>apktool d s.apk