# View SKD files from .apk

Tags: android, apk, reverse-engineering, apktool

I am trying to do reverse engineering of apk, I want to view the SDK and NDK files.
I tried multiple ways like apktool and opening apk in android studio, but all without success.Also if i edit the code and rebuild signed apk do i need to run it on rooted device.

Answer (score 2):

Procedure for decoding .apk files, step-by-step method:

Step 1:

> 1). Make a new folder and copy over the .apk file that you want to
>   decode.  2). Now rename the extension of this .apk file to .zip (e.g.
>   rename from filename.apk to filename.zip) and save it.  3). Now you
>   can access the classes.dex files, etc. At this stage you are able to
>   see drawables but not xml and java files, so continue.

Step 2:

> 1). Now extract this .zip file in the same folder (or NEW FOLDER). 
>   2). Download dex2jar and extract it to the same folder (or NEW
>   FOLDER).  3). Move the classes.dex file into the dex2jar folder.  4).
>   Now open command prompt and change directory to that folder (or NEW
>   FOLDER). 5). Then write d2j-dex2jar classes.dex (for mac terminal or
>   ubuntu write ./d2j-dex2jar.sh classes.dex) and press enter.  6). You
>   now have the classes.dex.dex2jar file in the same folder.  7).
>   Download java decompiler, double click on jd-gui, click on open file,
>   and open classes.dex.dex2jar file from that folder: now you get class
>   files.  8). Save all of these class files (In jd-gui, click File ->
>   Save All Sources) by src name. At this stage you get the java source
>   but the .xml files are still unreadable, so continue.

Step 3:

> 1). Now open another new folder
>
> 2). Put in the .apk file which you want to decode  3). Download the
>   latest version of apktool AND apktool install window (both can be
>   downloaded from the same link) and place them in the same folder  4).
>   Open a command window apktool d myApp.apk (where myApp.apk denotes the
>   filename that you want to decode)  5). now you get a file folder in
>   that folder and can easily read the apk's xml files. this solutions is
>   extracted from this StactOverflow site [Check Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

you can download all the required libraries from here [*libraries*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010367/how-to-decompile-an-apk-or-dex-file-on-android-platform)

Comment: I tried the above method,but i am still not able to view the SKD and NDK files.