# Using APKEasyTool, Can I get java or kotlin code except smail code?

Tags: android, compiler-construction, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I have completed apk file, but lost my project.
Is it possible to get java code from my apk file using easyapktool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decompile an APK or DEX file on Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010367/how-to-decompile-an-apk-or-dex-file-on-android-platform)

Comment: its possible only if you are having reverse mapping file, otherwise can`t get 100% out of an APK file

Comment: you can get back the code from your apk trivially(as long as you didn't use proguard) but it won't have the same variable/class names. use version control next time!

Comment: We recommend using Github Gitlab etc. @leeyang

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible however you can the kind of files, resources, used packages, etc from the apk. But i doubt if you can see the actual code.