# Customize Android Apps

Tags: android

Am trying to customize an android app according to my requirements. Where do I begin from? I've Android Studio installed. Can I modify the code, rebuild an apk, resign and install on my phone? If so how can I view the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Android applications are digitally signed, minified, and/or obfuscated and therefore not able to be decompiled, but you can try

[How to decompile an APK or DEX file on Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010367/how-to-decompile-an-apk-or-dex-file-on-android-platform)

But yes, assuming you could get the code, any text editor or IDE (such as Android Studio) and a supported build system (like Gradle) would work

Note: decompiled code doesn't contain any resources to rebuild the app with all its dependencies