# How to edit .aab file with Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-app-bundle

I have simple question. Is possible to edit my apk from .aab? I lost my project backup file. I just want to update my apk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate Apk file from aab file (android app bundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040047/generate-apk-file-from-aab-file-android-app-bundle)

Comment: Mostly...no, you'd have to use a decompiler and it's not gonna be a good time. But if you've got no other option, it's better than nothing.

Comment: I'd reallllllly try to recover the source files if you can, but if you can't, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21010367/208273).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update the code of the apk with the app bundle file(.aab).