# Android Studio project lost

Tags: android, mobile

I lost my Android Studio project because I accidentally deleted it, but I still have the app installed on my mobile. There is any chance to recover it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decompile an APK or DEX file on Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010367/how-to-decompile-an-apk-or-dex-file-on-android-platform)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file